# Deploying First WP Site with Understrap, Can't Find Required Resources

Tags: wordpress, gulp

I've transferred my database and entire Wordpress file structure over to the live site, but the live site is still looking for all its resources at localhost:8888/.

I looked back on what I did when getting started and I edited my `gulpfile.js` to include

```
var browserSyncOptions = {
  proxy: 'localhost:8888',
  notify: false
};
```

Thinking this was the issue, I switched it to `proxy: $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`, but still no luck. Any ideas for what I may be doing wrong?

Unfortunately I haven't been able to find a single bit of information about deploying an understrap themed site. Here are the docs for the theme though: https://understrap.com/demos/core/wp-content/themes/core-understrap/docs/.

Comment: Please follow step as per the url: https://torquemag.io/2016/02/move-wordpress-from-localhost-to-live-server/.  and replay me in case of any query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've transferred my database and entire Wordpress file structure over to the live site, but the live site is still looking for all its resources at localhost:8888/.

That is an easy to way to get into live server maintenance hell. UnderStrap is a unique theme package because it has strong npm dependencies running in the back-end that are appropriate for localhost development builds.   For that reason, Here is an alternative approach I recommend instead.

1. Install a clean vanilla version of WordPress on your live server.
2. Install and activate UnderStrap.zip on your live server through wp-admin.
3. Import/Export your posts and pages from your local site, onto the live site.  Add all media images.  Adjust your settings, install your plugins, and clear your cache.
4. Now use the file manager in your C-Panel to only upload all **modified** theme files from your localhost to your live server.
5. Test your site, then go live.

   - That is more of a manual process, but it has its benefits.  For one, you learn and see what each step looks like, you push up only what you need, you don't have localhost decencies running on your live site and the database is 100% targeted on live site content.

Answer (score 0):

If you can access the wp-admin of your live site there's a great plugin called Velvet Blues Update URLs that you can install.

Install it, go to Tools > Update URLs and enter the localhost address and then the live site address.

Always works great for me.

Answer (score 0):

Many developers have done this process by running its gulp dist when processing deployment. It will create dist folder which you can upload on the server. It contains all necessary files that supports running the scss. So try to use also the gulp dist-product as a "product" that the theme can be published and downloaded in the near future.